# Animating 2 views together hides one where the other view was

Tags: android, animation, xamarin.android, android-animation

I have 2 views (a button and a slider bar), one above the other, and I am animating the lower one out of frame and I want the other view to also animate down the same amount. My issue is that the spot where the lower view use to be clips out the top view. (See images). Both animations are triggered by a view model property change.

```
TimeView.Animate().TranslationYBy(ViewModel.IsShowingEmployees ? -TimeView.Height : TimeView.Height);
MyPositionButton.Animate().TranslationYBy(ViewModel.IsShowingEmployees ? -TimeView.Height : TimeView.Height);
```

Before Animation:
[image]

After Animation:
[image]

How do I get the lower view to stop clipping the upper one? I have attempted to alter the view's Z and TransitionZ properties to make sure the button is higher then the bar. I have also tried to set the visibility of the bar to Gone on animation completion. Also I have tried to use a TranslateAnimation so that I could have control over the Fill properties. None of these thing have worked.

Here is a look at the axml.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_area_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/under_list_view">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_container_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/time_view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:background="#ddffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_text_view"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="4:56PM"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/time_seek_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:max="1440"
            android:progress="700"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_scrubber_progress"
            android:thumb="@drawable/custom_scrubber_control"
            android:secondaryProgress="0"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/time_text_view" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/time_view"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/my_location_button"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ek_fab_button_ripple_white"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location_24p"
            android:tint="@color/gray_dark" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After switching on the "Show layout bounds", OP found out that he was animating the `Button` itself, not the `RelativeLayout`. After animating `RelativeLayout` no clipping would happen.

**Old answer**

Change the places of your `RelativeLayout`s, so that one with `ImageButton` is declared below of another with `SeekBar`. In that case the `ImageButton` will be drawn over `SeekBar`.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_area_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/under_list_view">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_container_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/time_view"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="44dp"
        android:background="#ddffffff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/time_text_view"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="4:56PM"
            android:textColor="@color/gray_dark"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />
        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/time_seek_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:max="1440"
            android:progress="700"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_scrubber_progress"
            android:thumb="@drawable/custom_scrubber_control"
            android:secondaryProgress="0"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/time_text_view" />
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/time_view"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/my_location_button"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ek_fab_button_ripple_white"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_my_location_24p"
            android:tint="@color/gray_dark" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention in the OP that this was one of the solutions I tried, it gets the same result.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot with "Show layout bounds" mode on?

Comment: That was the nudge I needed. While getting the SS with "ShowLayoutBounds" on, I noticed that I was animating the button itself and not its continuing layout, so the layout was clipping the button. I just make it animate the relative layout instead and all is good. \m/(><)\m/ Update your post with this info and I'll make it the accepted answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Nerves, updated. May the "show layout bound" be with you in such cases :-)